# Reactjs - how to move an element between components onClick of button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently new to learning Reactjs and I want to be able to move an element (say, just like a simple  header between two components (that I've made as two simple boxes). I got caught up on how to implement the button, I figure I should implement that as its own component since it has important functionality. The point I reached up to is below:

```
/*class MoveButton extends React.Component {
      handleClick() {
      alert("Button clicked");
  }

  render() {
     return (
       <button onClick={handleClick}>
         Click To Move
       </button>
    );
  }
 } */

 class BoxOne extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
      <div className="boxOne-container">
      </div>
   );
 }
}

   class BoxTwo extends React.Component {
     render() {
      return (
       <div className="boxTwo-container">
       </div>
     );
    }
   }

 function App() {
   return (
     <div>
       <BoxOne />
       <BoxTwo />
     </div>
   );
   }
 ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Be more specific. What do you want to move?

Comment: @dfsq I would like to use the button to move an <h1> header from BoxOne to BoxTwo, and vise versa, etc

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample of a 'moving button'

```
class MoveButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                Click To Move
            </button>
        );
    }
}

class BoxOne extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="boxOne-container">
                Box1
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class BoxTwo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="boxTwo-container">
                Box2
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { pos: 0 }
    }
    onClick() {
        this.setState({ pos: (this.state.pos + 1) % 3 })
    }
    render () { 
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.pos === 0 ? <MoveButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}/> : ''}
                <BoxOne />
                { this.state.pos === 1 ? <MoveButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}/> : ''}
                <BoxTwo />
                { this.state.pos === 2 ? <MoveButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}/> : ''}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function App() {
    return (
        <App />
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. Is there also simply a way I could move the text like "Box1" and "Box2" between the two box components when the button is clicked? (So the button would be staying in place)